# What is the GH-Pages workflow that is used on the Jekyll project?

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I have been looking at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll and I am wondering what workflow they would use to get the contents of docs folder on the master branch on gh-pages branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing to gh-pages is automated by a rake task.

You can have look at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/Rakefile#L162

To use this command, you just need to have Rake installed and run a **rake publish**.